# How can i accomplish this? Prefer to use regular html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to accomplish this without the use of jquery?

[image]

The width of the images will vary from small, medium and big. The products will have a property with size.

I thought about using just float left, but that wont work since the big picture will force the 2 left bottom once, down to the next line.

If i have to use jquery, which plugin is the best?

EDIT: The order of the list varies, which means the size of the pictures will not be at the same posistion always. Float left, float right wont work then

Comment: Is the list of images dynamic (in number and size) or will there always be exactly 8 smaller images with the same dimensions and exactly 1 big image with the same dimension?

Comment: Its all going to be dynamic

Comment: In that case I would suggest using Masonry, as in Salman A's answer.

Answer (score 4):

May be you are looking for [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/):

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery. Think of it as the
>   flip-side of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements
>   horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically,
>   positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result
>   minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like
>   a mason fitting stones in a wall.

Comment: Yeah, that does exactly what i want. But i'm just curious if it isn't possible doing without a jquery plugin.

Comment: It is always possible without JQuery... in the worst case, you could just copy&paste JQuery's source code, and it would work. The question is -- why do that?

Comment: The layout you posted can be made in pure HTML+CSS. But if image dimensions are not known or they vary too much then I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

make box which will contain bottom 4 cars(small ones) and float that left

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Use this div strucure maybe? So red has full width and other are 50%

Comment: The position of the small and big pictures will vary, so i cant i guess?

Comment: better use some js ;). jquery masonry should be fine, as someone suggested.

Comment: I guess thats the only solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following structure

```
    <div>
       <img src="smallimg1/>
       <img src="smallimg2/> 
       <img src="smallimg3/>
       <img src="smallimg4/> 

        </div>

        <div>

   <div id="div1"> 
       <img src="smallimg1/>
       <img src="smallimg2/> 
       <img src="smallimg3/>
       <img src="smallimg4/> 
    </div>
    <div id="div2"> 
       <img src="bigimg1/>          
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS code

```
img
{
float:left;
}
#div1
{
width:50%;
}
#div2
{
width:50%;
}
```